# Use Spreadsheet Names as Variables in Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, function

I have different models and initialValues stored in different sheets in an Excel File called RateMatrix1. My models are WIN, WSW, WPA, WFR... and my initialValues are WI, WS, WP, WF... and the sheets on Excel are named exactly as such.

Now, I would like to write a function that uses the name of the model and the initialValues as "sheetnames" below. I was wondering if there is a way to do so in python.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def MLA(model, initialValues)
    RMatrix=(pd.read_excel("C:\Anaconda3\RateMatrix1.xlsx", sheetname="model", skiprows=0)).as_matrix() #read the matrix values from excel spreadsheet, and converts the values to a matrix
    initialAmount = (pd.read_excel("C:\Anaconda3\RateMatrix1.xlsx", sheetname="initialValues", skiprows=0)).as_matrix() #read the column matrix (initial values) from excel spreadsheet, and converts the values to a matrix
    return np.dot(RMatrix,initialAmount)

print(MLA(WIN,WI))
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind...I found a solution.

For anyone else looking to do the same,here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def MLA(model, initialValues)
    RMatrix=(pd.read_excel("C:\Anaconda3\RateMatrix1.xlsx", sheetname=model, skiprows=0)).as_matrix() #read the matrix values from excel spreadsheet, and converts the values to a matrix
    initialAmount = (pd.read_excel("C:\Anaconda3\RateMatrix1.xlsx", sheetname=initialValues, skiprows=0)).as_matrix() #read the column matrix (initial values) from excel spreadsheet, and converts the values to a matrix
return np.dot(RMatrix,initialAmount)

print(MLA("WIN","WI"))
```